# How can i detect if the player is inside an explosion radius?

Tags: unity, collision-detection, gameobject

I'm making a driving game, there are enemies which spawn on the side of road and when my player car gets close, they fire a rocket in front of the player. I need to detect if the car is within a certain radius of the explosion center. So when I can detect that I'm assuming I can then use rb.AddExplosiveForce to make the car fly a bit or something.

What is the recommended way to get the blast radius collider (or equivalent) and detect if the player is inside it?

Comment: You can use : https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.OverlapSphere.html

Example https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddExplosionForce.html

It's very basic.

Comment: As an aside, "can I assign a collider to an explosion?" - well, did you try? Did anything stop you? ;) Some questions are best answered by diving in and giving it a shot, even if you don't know if it's the "right" way (we so rarely have unambiguous right ways to do things in games ;) )

Comment: @DMGregory I do agree with your comments. But from my experience I've found that if I dive in to often without reading and asking first, thats when i sometimes end up in an absolute complete mess and end up literally scrapping the project and/or some of the assets/scripts I put into it. But im quite far in to making this game so I was trying to avoid that. I was looking for the recommended way (or rather is it not recommended to put the extra collider as opposed to your sqrMagnitute solution below). The game is working nicely now and getting near complete thanks to yours and others help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For an instantaneous radius check, you can use the [OverlapSphere](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.OverlapSphere.html) method like so:

```
Collider[] hits = Physics.OverlapSphere(
          explosionCenter,
          explosionRadius,
          layerMaskToCheck );
```

This gives you an array containing all colliders touched by the explosion's spherical volume. You can then iterate through that array to apply forces & damage to their corresponding objects.

For better control over performance, you can use the [NonAlloc](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.OverlapSphereNonAlloc.html) version where you prepare a reusable buffer in advance, so it can fill that existing array with its results instead of allocating new ones and creating garbage to collect later.

However, if only the player is affected, then you can skip the physics queries entirely and just use a distance check to detect whether the Player object is within a given radius of the hit point:

```
 if((player.transform.position - explosionCenter)
   .sqrMagnitude < explosionRadius * explosionRadius)
```

(Here using a common trick of comparing squared values to skip an unnecessary square root operation — this isn't terribly important if you're only doing it a few times, just a habit a lot of us are in)

Comment: thank you for your detailed answer my friend. im confused by LayerMaskToCheck but I may well understand it once i get going and once i have a read of the docs. I'll give this a try right now :)

Comment: You can leave that parameter out if you don't need to filter your results to particular layers: it will catch everything by default. If you need to exclude certain layers (say you have static scenery with colliders you'd like to ignore) you can expose a `public LayerMask layersToHit;` field on your script — this will give you a checklist of layers in the Inspector that you can toggle on & off as needed, similar to the layer settings on lights & cameras.

Comment: ahh awesome, so i will need this method later when i start to create a more complex and object filled world. But your solution at the bottom seems great as I am only letting my players car be affected by the explosions. I'm still just trying to get my head around where exactly to use it in my code but thanks to your answer im hoping ill have it covered soon

Comment: It would probably go in the OnTriggerEnter or OnCollisionEnter routine of your rocket (depending on whether it's using a trigger collider), so it gets called when the rocket strikes a solid surface.

Comment: ok sorry i am definitely a bit thick! I am stuck lol! I assume hitPoint is the centre of the explosion, which if the case is fine i have that bit. But sqrMagnitude , I assume is Magnitute squared? But the object has no speed at all, its stopped and then i make the explosion

Comment: i have a rocket model which is child of the rocketLauncher,  the launcher has the script and a large circle collider so when the car gets inside it , the same script will fire the rocket, then each frame it checks the rockets height is higher than the car and when its not an explosion is instantiated.

Comment: probably the complete wrong way to have done it, as I am just hacking away by myself a lot of time without following any guides lol

Comment: ok I do have a method already called RocketExplode() which does work it plays the sound, makes explosion. But I dont know how to get the rockets magnitute

Comment: Then there's your answer: when you instantiate the explosion, perform the radius check to see if the player is inside. Yes, hitPoint is the center of the explosion — sorry, I'm on my phone and didn't spot that I'd changed nomenclature partway through — fixed now. The magnitude we're talking about here is the distance between the explosion center and the player's position. It's not a speed or anything you need to derive beyond the formula given above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62618/discussion-between-super-megabrobro-and-dmgregory).